# ASP.NET MVC Routes: Defining route including subpaths

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Let's say I want to forward all requests at /js/* to a `JavaScript` controller `Index` method. In other words, these routes should all invoke `JavaScriptController.Index()`:

```
/js/root/index.css
/js/user/account/index.css
/js/master.css
```

What would the route definition be in my `Global.asax.cs` file?

This doesn't seem to work:

```
routes.MapRoute("JavaScript", "js/{*path}",
    new { controller = "JavaScriptController", action = "Index" });
```

The breakpoint is never invoked during Debug mode with:

```
public class JavaScriptController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public void Index(string path)
    {
        var browser = HttpContext.Request.Browser;
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have the controller shortname in the route default values i.e:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
     "JavaScript", 
     "js/{*path}",     
      new { controller = "javascript", action = "Index" }
   );
```

This would work.